# How to speed up oracle normal statement bulk operations?

Tags: java, oracle, groovy, batch-processing, ojdbc

I'm developing tool to continuously export changes from MongoDb to Oracle database.

I have problem with execution batch operation(Oracle).

```
static void save(List result) {
    withBatchConnection { Statement stm ->
        result.each { String line ->
                stm.addBatch(line)
        }
    }
}

static withConnection(Closure closure) {
    def conn = null
    boolean success = false
    while (!success) {
        try {
            conn = getConnection()
            closure.call(conn)
            success = true
        } catch (e) {
            log.error('Connection problem', e)
            log.error(e, e)
            log.info('Retrying for 30 sec')
            sleep(30000)
        } finally {
            conn?.close()
        }
    }
}

static withTransactionConnection(Closure closure) {
    withConnection { Sql sql ->
        OracleConnection conn = sql.getConnection() as OracleConnection
        conn.setAutoCommit(false)
        closure.call(conn)
        conn.commit()
    }
}

static withBatchConnection(Closure closure) {
    withTransactionConnection { Connection conn ->
        def statement = conn.createStatement()
        closure.call(statement)
        statement.executeBatch()
        statement.close()
    }
}
```

Problem is i cant use prepared statement because order of operations is very important.

When I'm saving to MySql with Rewrite Batched Statements its like 10k operations per second. For Oracle is 400 operations/s

Is any chance to make it faster?

I'm using OJDBC 7 and groovy 2.4.7

Comment: One important difference between Oracle and MySQL is the "commit" phase of transaction in Oracle, which doesn't exist in MySQL. Could be the source of what you observe. Is there a commit to your database after each step? If so, avoid it, and commit every e.g. 10000 updates.

Comment: I don't see what a prepared statement and order of operations has to do with each other

Comment: Check if your connections have auto commit set to 'on' by default, meaning a commit after every statement.

Comment: @john16384  In prepared statement you can execute only same type of operations, like inserts to same table. In my situation there are:  Insert into a, Insert into b, delete from a; insert into a;

Answer (score 0):

Please set the array size from client side to maximum and try

Comment: An array size over 1k probably won't make much of a difference.